# Magento - get the details of the website a category is assigned to

Tags: magento, categories

I have a multi store setup and I am trying to determine the website to which a category is assigned.
I have the following:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId)->getStoreId();
```

but this doesn't seem to show the right info (always shows Id of 1 even if I change the cat id to one from another website).

I have also tried the following :

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId)->getStore()->getName();
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId)->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId)->getWebsite();
```

How can I determine the website that the category is assigned to?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stores or websites?

**Store ids**…

```
$categoryId = 10;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$storeIds = $category->getStoreIds();
```

**Website ids**…

```
$categoryId = 10;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
$categoryIds = $category->getPathIds();

$stores = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()
    ->loadByCategoryIds($categoryIds);

$websiteIds = array_unique($stores->getColumnValues('website_id'));
```

Comment: Thanks Drew. Works perfectly. However, it seems like getColumnValues can return an array (as indicated by you use of the plural $websiteIds). Why would this be? Surely a category can only be assigned to one website (within the websites root category)?